# Search for method calls and field references of class within a scope

Tags: java, eclipse, search, static-analysis

Given the following example:

```
public class Foo {
    public void myMethod(Bar arg) {
        SomeOtherClass.baz(arg);
        ....
    }
}
```

I would like to have a way to perform a search of `Bar.*` within the scope of `Foo.myMethod()` and all methods that `arg` is passed to.  In other words, where are all the places within the code where a method is called or a field is referenced on `arg` for all code-paths starting with `Foo.myMethod()`?

Notes: I would prefer to do this in Eclipse but am also open to using other tools (under Linux would be great -- windows if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at a (the?) great IDE: **IDEA IntelliJ** (12 has just been released :)) and its famous **Structural Search**: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/ssr.html

Comment: An IDE agnostic solution would have been nice but, this actually solved the problem for me, thanks!  I actually didn't realize IJ 12 was just released so I decided to give it a look ... although, I ran into a road-block getting play integration to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771192/playframework-plugin-non-functional-in-intellij-idea-12  (forgive me for this link being a bit off-topic)