# Playframework Plugin non-functional in IntelliJ IDEA 12

Tags: scala, playframework, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

I have just downloaded and installed IntelliJ IDEA 12 (Ultimate Edition), under Ubuntu, with high hopes that I could cash-in on IJ's tight integration with Scala and the Play Framework.

I have a fully functional install of Play at `/home/ryan/play-2.0.4` and from searching around, it seems that all one has to do is perform a `play idea` on a play project at the command-line and simply open the project in IntelliJ.

However, if I do this: I can't even verify that the Playframework plug-in is even active/functioning.  There is no syntax highlighting in Play config files or templates, absolutely no Playframework options in the pull-down menu.  If I right-click the project, choose "Add Framework support ..." and "Play" is not even on the list, I can't just create a new "Play" project from scratch in the IDE either (not sure if that is even supported).

If I click `File -> Settings -> Play Configuration`, I have the Home and Working directory set to: `/home/ryan/play-2.0.4`.  I should note that I am using Play under Eclipse with no issues (except there isn't any Play integration with Eclipse --- hence the reason why I am giving this a try in IJ).  If I didn't know any better: I'd declare IJ 12's Play support as a miserable failure, but given all the postings suggesting that play 2.0 integration with IJ 12 is "very easy" - perhaps there is something I am missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most probably you need to download and/or install `Play 2.0 Support` plugin + dependencies (most probably you will need to find it in `Browse repositories` section, it is not the same plugin as bundled `Playframework support`!)

I can ensure you that I'm just sitting and playing with Play 2.0 in Idea 12 with new support, and it works quite nice.

Go to `Settings` > `Plugins` section and check if you have newest version of mentioned plugin and if isn't blocked by some error (ie. missing dependency), try to resolve all missing dependencies, restart the IDE, and compile (or run) your applications at least once.

I didn't test it to the end yet, but I can see large progress in the support especially in templates and controllers. `routes` file allow easily navigate to the target actions, but as I can see there is no syntax highlighting in conf file.

There is even possible now to run and debug Play application from the menu.

In general if you'll enable the Play plugin you will see it for sure :)

Comment: But, what dependencies?  I am looking at Settings -> Plugins now and I see "Playframework Support" (which is bundled) both present and "checked".  I'm not seeing any error anywhere -- perhaps I'm not looking in the right place?  I've invalidated caches, tried a `play clean-all` before re-running `play idea` ... still no love.   I can't even tell if the play plug-in "likes" my play installation because even if I change the paths (under `File -> Settings -> Play Configuration`) to something bogus: no change in behavior.

Comment: You need to download `Play 2.0 Support` as well from the repositories then. I tested it first time long time ago and apparently it is not bundled, but is required.

Comment: Aha! That's the type of thing I'd expect to have missed ... just installed it: will check it now.

Comment: Although now it doesn't seem to recognize my routes file, I'll investigate

Comment: I had to install PLay 2.0 plugin which depends on Scala plugin afaik, (run play idea == obvious) play compile from play's console and basic functionality (build, rebuilds after change, click->goto view) works fine. InteliJ recognizes ok methods and can build project. But I can't see "play with play framework" option anymore. I'm using Play + Java right now

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to install additional plugins. You only have to run your application once, and afterwards IntelliJ highlights everything etc.

Look here: http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5473435?tstart=0#5473435