# Play2 project in Intellij 12

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

Can someone explain me how to import your idea project for Play2 support on Intellij 12?

I've just bought the upgrade from version 10 to 12. It used to work fine with Intellij 10 (with scala support only). When using `play idea` and importing the project on Intellij 12 it doesn't seem to work, there is no more highlighting, even in scala files that were actually working with version 10.

It seems I'm not the only one to have troubles with Play2 support in Intellij 12 so if someone can help it would be nice :)

Comment: No you're not the only one (that's the good news :) ) - duplicate of [Playframework Plugin non-functional in IntelliJ IDEA 12](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771192/playframework-plugin-non-functional-in-intellij-idea-12)

Comment: I had the same problem. The solution was easy => http://stackoverflow.com/a/13845350/1870829

:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check that you have installed **Scala** and **Play 2.0 Support** plug-ins [from the repository](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html).

Then check that `.scala` extension is assigned to `Scala Files` in `Settings` | `File Types`.

See also these links:

- [Getting Started with Play 2.0 in IntelliJ IDEA 12](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/12/getting-started-with-play-20-in-intellij-idea-12/)
- [Play Framework 2.0 Tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0)

Comment: Thanks. I thought the plugin was already installed (but it could have been play1 plugin...). I wasn't able to find anything related to play2 until I did "browse plugin repositories". Don't really know why because I never had to click on that to download an intellij plugin...

Comment: The "Getting Started with Play 2.0 in IntelliJ IDEA 12" link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Well, importing an existing Play 2 project with IntelliJ is still not very easy, even with the new Play plug-in.

Upvote this issue to get a nice Import utility for your existing Play 2 projects.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-5209